# Regex: Find words with multiple periods

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

I am given a task that will require regex to find a string out of a paragraph. I need to find a string that looks *something.like.this* but is not limited to *looking.something.like.this.also*.

Using the paragraph above as an example, this expression would have pulled out "something.like.this" and "looking.something.like.this.also"

```
Must me A-z, no =+[]{}\/?*&^%$#@!*, can include .()-
```

I thought about checking to see if there are multiple periods between spaces.

Comment: Go here and try some out: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Is this regex what you're looking for?](https://regex101.com/r/sC2yC6/4)

```
(?:[A-Za-z(\)-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z\(\)-]+)+){2,}
```

**Additional criterias in comments**

- Cannot match `...` .

  > This would also match ... which is not included in the OP's requirements. –  juharr
  >
  > @Zsw i didnt think about it, but @juharr is correct, i cannot have ... –  Bernie
- Cannot match consecutive periods.

  > What about consecutive periods like `this..has...multiple....periods` - juharr
  >
  > @juharr i should also ignore this, but it will be highly unlikely that will appear in any of the text it will run against. –  Bernie
- Cannot match `one.two`.

  > @Zsw one.two cannot be matched. I found using [A-Za-z.()-]+.[A-Za-z.()-]+.[A-Za-z.()-]+ works for this, but how do i ignore the ... or this...this..this? –  Bernie

Comment: YES! this works, by chance can you provide an explanation?

Comment: does not match _"looking.something.like.this.also"_.  Consider editing.  Also incorrectly matches `miss.piggy.has.really.big.chubby.fingers.and.cant.use.a.regular.rotary.dial.telephone`

Comment: @MickyDuncan +1 for example! Is there a limit of characters regex will find?

Comment: @MickyDuncan How is the second example an incorrect match? It seems to fit with Bernie's requirement. Also, after adding a `g` flag, it does match `looking.something.like.this.also`. https://regex101.com/r/sC2yC6/2

Comment: This would also match `...` which is not included in the OP's requirements.

Comment: @juharr It would, but the OP said that the strings `can include .()`, so it should fit the requirement, I think. Unless Bernie would like to clarify?

Comment: @Zsw i didnt think about it, but @juharr is correct, i cannot have `...`

Comment: @juharr i should also ignore this, but it will be highly unlikely that will appear in any of the text it will run against.

Comment: To add to this. i also can not have `site.com` match this.

Comment: @Bernie Why not? `site.com` seems to fit with your requirement. Is it specifically that you want to ignore `.com`? Or that `one.two` in general cannot be matched?

Comment: @Zsw `one.two` cannot be matched. I found using `[A-Za-z\.\(\)-]+\.[A-Za-z\.\(\)-]+\.[A-Za-z\.\(\)-]+` works for this, but how do i ignore the `...` or `this...this..this`?

Comment: @Bernie My new edit should satisfy all your requirements now.